# there was a error with the network 400 in youtube channel in android

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
                @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayer = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
                youtubePlayer.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
                YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaying() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPaused() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopped() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekTo(int i) {

                }
        };

        YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {

                }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }
        };

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {

                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(PlayList_ID);

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your question has no question.

Comment: Top of your text is not in code

Comment: API_KEY -> replace this with your API key

Comment: String API_KEY = "xxxx";
        String PlayList_ID = xxxx"; Top code